# apache "Access forbidden! Error 403" when creating alias to a directory in home

Tags: linux, apache, httpd.conf, mod-alias

I'm new to apache. 
I'm trying to create an alias to my project folder which is in home/Documents/Projects/blog directory.

I added this to httpd configs:

```
Alias /blog "/home/ehsan/Documents/Projects/blog/ui/dist"   
<Directory "/home/ehsan/Documents/Projects/blog/ui/dist">
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    AllowOverride All
    Options FollowSymlinks
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I did this also:

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /home/ehsan/Documents/Projects/leitner/ui/dist
```

but I get "403 Access forbidden!" error.

I did the same thing for phpmyadmin and it works.

I read somewhere that apache should have access to all the higher level directories. is that true?

apache version: 2.4.41 (Unix)

os: manjaro 18

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make apache the owner of the folder which it's gonna make changes in it.
Try this:
head to your project directory as below

`cd /home/ehsan/Documents/Projects/leitner`

and then :

`chown -R www-data:www-data ui/`

if there was any error going on, send the log of apache here would be helpful

Comment: (13)Permission denied: access to /leitner denied (filesystem path '/home/ehsan/Documents') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path. is it wrong to make apache owner of these directories security-wise?